# COUNT(*) return wrong number

Tags: mysql

It seems I don't get it something. Please consider this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` 
FROM (`exp_channel_titles` ch) 
JOIN `exp_channel_data` cd ON `cd`.`entry_id`=`ch`.`entry_id` 
LEFT JOIN `exp_matrix_data` md ON `md`.`entry_id`=`ch`.`entry_id` and field_id = 14 
LEFT JOIN `exp_assessment_users` au ON `au`.`entry_id`=`ch`.`entry_id` 
WHERE ch.channel_id = 4 GROUP BY `ch`.`entry_id`
```

it returns `2`

but if I change it to

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`exp_channel_titles` ch) 
JOIN `exp_channel_data` cd ON `cd`.`entry_id`=`ch`.`entry_id` 
LEFT JOIN `exp_matrix_data` md ON `md`.`entry_id`=`ch`.`entry_id` and field_id = 14 
LEFT JOIN `exp_assessment_users` au ON `au`.`entry_id`=`ch`.`entry_id` 
WHERE ch.channel_id = 4 GROUP BY `ch`.`entry_id`
```

result is 1 row only. How so?

Comment: try with INNER JOIN instead

Comment: What does count(ch.channel_id) and count(ch.entry_id) return

Comment: and you can tell us what select 1 FROM ur statement returns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're grouping, which means internally matching rows are collapsed into a single entity. e.g. consider a fake table like this:

```
field
-----
a
a
```

Yes, a one field table, with two records, both of which have the value `a` in them.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY field
```

`group by` will find all fields which have the same value, and collapse them down into a SINGLE record, so your two records of `a` become one row in the result set, and you end up with

```
field
-----
a
```

But doing

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY field
```

changes things. Now the DB will literally count how many records were collapsed down into the single row of result set. So you still get a SINGLE row in the result set, which contains a count of how many rows were collapsed by the `group by`:

```
count(*)
--------
2
```

One row, with a value of 2, because there were two rows with `a`.

Now if you had a table with more records:

```
field
-----
a
a
b
c
c
c
```

You would get:

```
SELECT * ... GROUP BY field

field
-----
a
b
c

SELECT count(*), field ... GROUP BY field

count(*)   field
----------------
2          a
1          b
3          c
```

again, 3 rows of results, but note how the count represents how many of each grouped field there are in the original table.

Comment: Superb explanation, realy awesome

Comment: MySQL is very misleading when using GROUP BY.  Other DB only allows aggregated columns in the SELECT clause or columns specified in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: in many cases, the mysql behavior is actually better. forcing only aggregated/grouped data in the query imposes assumptions on the tables which may not be true (or necessary). of course, allowing the other direction imposes other assumptions that can blow up in the opposite direction.

Comment: what actual rows number? you need to explain your data better.

Comment: I have found sulution count(distinct (ch.entry_id))